# Mixing PCL libraries and non-PCL code

Tags: c#, xamarin, cross-platform

I did not find a similar question, lets see if that holds true :-).

I want to use C# based PCL libraries also in "normal" aka plain windows x86 C# projects (instead of just using them inside cross-platform (Xamarin) projects).

The reason for this is basically back porting for legacy projects: I want to switch to PCL code for future projects and use new features also in old code. As you can imagine, these projects are at least partially developed for older version of the C# runtime (namely 4.0).

My question is this: Can I expect the libraries to behave similar, that means if my basic unit tests pass, I am good to go? Or is there random behavior that makes it hard to validate the proper functioning of a library? I am especially worried about articles/questions I read in regards to HttpClient code behaving unexpectedly, but not even consistently wrong across various runtime versions (4.0 - 4.5). Thus the team would chase issues that cannot be reproduced and ruin the support teams weekends :-P.

I am not so sure if the question is easy to understand in all aspects, please let me know if it makes sense. If it is toooo confusing I may rephrase it after people have made suggestions... .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the project properties of you PCL, you can check what versions of .Net and what Platforms you want to support.
In the background, you selection geht's mapped down to a portable subset profile where only those APIs are available, that are supported on all your selected platforms.

(PCLs are not a Xamarin specific thing though.)

There are some cases where platform implementation details leak through, for example with timers (they aren't even included in some portable subsets).

Your Unit Tests will probably pass, and once you notice some specific problems, you can still add additional testing there.

For HttpClient, I'd recommend dependency injecting some platform specific client anyway (like with [modernhttpclient](https://www.nuget.org/packages/modernhttpclient)) just for performance reasons.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. I will try to see where this gets me.